# Mount Phyical Sata HDD to Two VM's at the same time?

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, mount, sata

I am running proxmox on an HP Proliant ML350 G5. I want to Mount a Physical Sata hard drive to two VM for simultaneous Read/Write. I can add the disk to the VM's but will data corruption or errors occur if it is mounted twice?

It is a 4TB GPT single partition device.

Comment: Bad idea https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9IkC-1kO8Ao

Comment: Could you elaborate? @SeanClt

Comment: What you describe will result in data corruption, what you actually want to do, is out the HDD into a NAS and call it a day

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured this one out... as @Ramhound Suggested the solution was to add the drive to a NAS array. This way the drive would be mounted once but accessible to multiple VM's over a network ate the same time!

Comment: Or significantly more efficient, let the host OS mount it and share with the VMs.